# SQL - pulling data where timestamp is between now and six months ago

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I would like to get data that's within the last 6 months. I have a time stamp stored but its stored as an int(11) rather then time stamp in the database.

would would be the correct sql statement to pull this data? (below is the statement I have tried but pulls 0 results - possibly due to the fact its stored as int rather then timestamp)

```
SELECT * FROM `Main_Stats` WHERE `Dates` >= now() - INTERVAL 6 month
```

Comment: Pls post ur sample data in int(11).

Comment: mysql or sql server? which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `Main_Stats`
WHERE from_unixtime(`Dates`,'%Y-%m-%d') >= now() - INTERVAL 6 month
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `unix_timestamp`.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `Main_Stats` WHERE `Dates` >= unix_timestamp(now()-interval 6 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Main_Stats`
WHERE `Dates` >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```